# Change mysql logging level when using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to suppress `[INFO]` level messages from MySQL when running `docker-compose up`. My entry in docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7.28
  ports:
    - 3307:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
  volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I've tried looking for [additional environment variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html) but I don't see anything that seems like it will control the logging level.

Is there a method that doesn't require any additional file changes beyond docker-compose.yml? If not, how else can this be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

Try `--log_error_verbosity=2` command option. Value `2` means "errors and warnings", you can use `1` for "errors only" (see [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual / 5.4.2.4 Error Log Filtering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log-filtering.html)).

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7.28
  ports:
    - 3307:3306
  command: --log_error_verbosity=2   # errors and warnings
  environment:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true'
  volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```